# auto creat table row when other table add row

Tags: java, sql, database

i have 2 table 
1 persons(email,name)
2 location(email)

now when i add a person to persons table i want the db  auto creat a row in location whit the person email (that i just add to persons).

i try to do it white PRIMARY KEY, and FOREIGN KEY but no succses.

thank you all.

this what i try :

```
       CREATE TABLE Persons
        (
       Email char(50) PRIMARY KEY,

           First_Name char(50))  



      CREATE TABLE location
         (
         email char(50),
         FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES Persons(email)
           )
```

but when i add to persons person its not added to location too.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a trigger to do this not a foreign key.

The FK just enforces that a row cannot be inserted in `location` without a corresponding record in `Persons`

But `email` is a very wide choice for a primary key as well as unstable (see [is email address a bad primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3804108/73226)) and the whole design seems odd.

What is the `location` table for? Does this have a 1:many relationship with `Persons`? Where are the other columns? What is the PK of `location`?

Comment: first of all thanks i will see about this trigger, and this not my real tables it's just for the example. :-)

Comment: @dan - What RDBMS are you using? (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...)

Comment: @dan Ah If it was one I was familiar with I would have put some example trigger code in my answer but it's not!